# Information from the git tag object

Tags: git, hook, bitbucket, githooks, git-tag

Do you have any ideas what kind of information does git tag object carry?

The point is I would like to analyze it when I make git hook (preferably server-side).

Comment: Make different kinds of tags and `git cat-file -p $(git rev-parse <tag>)`

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks. It works even with just `git cat-file -p <tag>`

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any ideas what kind of information does git tag object carry?

In git there are 2 types of tag .

- regular tag
- anotated tag

Regular tag contains only the SHA-1 of the commit while annotated tag contains full information like any other commit.

Comment: When you create tags, you do not create actual commits with file modifications. Consequently, there is nothing to verify [git tags](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/git).

So, how can it contains the information as any other commit?

Comment: I agree tag is simply a pointer to a git commit, it does not store any content beside the tag metadata

Comment: An annotated tag does not contain *"full information like any other commit"* as it doesn't have an *author* filed which a commit does have. The only reference I could find is the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) but you can easily verify this yourself by running `git cat-file -p <tag-name>` on an annotated tag that you created. Only the `GIT_COMMITTER_X` variables have any effect on the `git tag` command (tested with Git 2.9.2).